# skipping non-plain index rt (sphinx 2.1.6)

Tags: sphinx

There is the question. Sphinx, version 2.1.6. I used to rt(real time) index, but when indexing display message in koncole:

```
using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
skipping non-plain index 'rt'...
```

But at a connection to sphinxbase and write query `mysql> desc rt - displays:`

```
+------------+--------+
| Field      | Type   |
+------------+--------+
| id         | bigint |
| id         | field  |
| first_name | field  |
| last_name  | field  |
+------------+--------+
```

This is default data?? They do not meet my request. How to work with index rt?

Sphinx.conf.

```
source database
{
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
        sql_user                = test
        sql_pass                = test
        sql_db                  = community
        sql_port                = 3306



        mysql_connect_flags     = 32 # enable compression

        sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query_pre           = SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF 
}

source rt : database
{   
        sql_query_range         = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM mbt_accounts

        sql_query               = SELECT id AS 'accountId', first_name AS 'fname', last_name AS 'lname' FROM  mbt_accounts WHERE id >= 0 AND id<= 1000


        sql_range_step = 1000

        sql_ranged_throttle = 1000 # milliseconds


}

index rt
{
    source          = rt
        type                    = rt
        path                    = /etc/sphinxsearch/rtindex
        rt_mem_limit            = 700M

    rt_field                = accountId
        rt_field                = fname
        rt_field                = lname

        rt_attr_string          = fname
        rt_attr_string          = lname

        charset_type            = utf-8

        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, -, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451
}


searchd
{
        listen                  = localhost:9312 # port for API
        listen                  = localhost:9306:mysql41 #port for a SphinxQL

        log                     = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
        binlog_path         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/

        query_log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
        query_log_format        = sphinxql

        pid_file                = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid

        workers                 = threads

        max_matches             = 1000

        read_timeout            = 5

        client_timeout          = 300

        max_children            = 30    

        max_packet_size         = 8M

        binlog_flush            = 2

        binlog_max_log_size     = 90M

        thread_stack            = 8M

        expansion_limit         = 500

        rt_flush_period         = 1800

        collation_server        = utf8_general_ci

        compat_sphinxql_magics  = 0

        prefork_rotation_throttle       = 100

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`indexer` only works with indexes that have a 'source' - ie plain disk indexesd. ie indexer does the stuff in the source to get the data to create the index.

RT (Real Time) indexes work very differently. `indexer` is not involved with RT indexes at all. They are handled totally by `searchd`.

To add data to a RT index, you need to run a bunch of SphinxQL commands (INSERT, UPDATE etc) that actually add the data to the index.

(DESCRIBE works, because searchd knows the 'structure' of the index (you told it via the rt_field etc) - even if never inserted any data)

---

Ah, I think you are asking why the structure is different. That's probably because the index was probably created before, you modified sphinx.conf. If you change the definiton of a RT index, you need to 'destroy' the index, to allow it be recreated again.

The simplest way is to shutdown searchd, delete the index files, delete the binlog (it no longer relevent) and then restart searchd.

```
searchd --stopwait
rm /etc/sphinxsearch/rtindex*
rm /path/to/binlog*  #(you dont define a path, so it must be the default, which varies) 
searchd #(starts searchd again)
```